# How to prevent lines below a certain line from running in python if a certain condition is met?

Tags: python

So i have an if statement, and i want to prevent the lines below the from running when the condition for the if statement is met.

```
import turtle
if password not in ("password"):
    print("access denied.")
    turtle.bgcolor("red")
    turtle.write("access denied.", font=style)
    turtle.done()
    #i want to prevent all lines from the rest of the script following this line from running
```

Comment: Do you want the program to exit?

Comment: Incidentally, do you understand that `if password not in ("password"):` will allow any combination of letters in `password` to be accepted, e.g. `p`, `pa`, `ss`, `word`, `d` would all be valid

Comment: One solution (to avoid everything being inside an `if` statement or having to use `sys.exit()` is to use functions. If your main program is in a function, just don't call it if the password check doesn't work. It would help if you would clarify exactly what you do want, as people are currently writing answers guessing your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try putting all of the code that code into a while loop and at the end of your if statement if the if condition is met add break so:

```
import turtle

while True:
    if password not in ("password"):
        print("access denied.")
        turtle.bgcolor("red")
        turtle.write("access denied.", font=style)
        turtle.done()
        break
    else:
        'whatever next condition is'
```

its hard to tell exactly without seeing more testable code but I think this would do it for you

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

It would end the program immediately (and exit it) but that's not elegant nor pythonic.

It would be better to throw an exception thus ending the execution of the program if the access is denied and to catch it and perform the actions you wanted to.

You can read about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).